# How to get the last answer of the recursion directly in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Here is the main part of my code in Prolog:

```
state(N, Sf) :-
    get_initial_state('test.csv',S),
    state_sequence(N, S, Sf).

state_sequence(N, S, S).
state_sequence(N, S, Sf) :-
    transition_state(S, S, [], Sn),
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    state_sequence(N1, Sn, Sf).
```

transition_state is just a set of rules which does not matter here. And it is a recursion which keeps going to get value of next state until N reaches 0.

Then for example I want the 48th result of state. So my query is

```
state(48,S).
```

Then I need to keep pressing ; and prolog keeps telling me next state and then until 48th it results in false.
So how can I get the 48th result directly without telling me results of each state??

Comment: you may try to change the first clause of `state_sequence` with `state_sequence(0, S, S).`

Comment: @gusbro is correct. `state_sequence(N, S, S).` succeeds for *any* value of `N`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to generate all solutions using `findall/3`, then get the solution you want. This is a simple example to show you the idea:

```
test(1,0).
test(2,0).
test(3,0).
test(4,0).
test(5,0).
test(6,0).

getNthSolution(Sol,N):-
    findall(S,test(S,0),L),
    nth1(N,L,Sol).

?- getNthSolution(S,3)
S = 3
```